# Cant clearInterval and then trigger another setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a list of users where clicking on each user I get a different timestamp from which I am showing a timer which is placed in a span with id #timer

```
<span id="timer"></span>
```

And this works as it is supposed to work.

**Here is a jsfiddle.**
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/largan/hsr17x4k/32/)

It seems that the `clearInterval(x);` doesn't stop the previous timer though, but start a new timer, and I get this (two timers at the same time)

[image]

I have tried also to use `window.clearInterval(x);` but it didnt work either. Also tried setting `var x` inside the `$(document).on('click', '.list', function()` as well as outside, but nothing works.

Comment: Can you post a complete repro of the issue? It's hard to understand because of scoping issues with `x`

Comment: it is hard to post everything. But I will try my best to make a working sample

Comment: Definitely a scope issue. `x` is declared within the scope of the #timer click function, the list click function can't access the out of scope var

Comment: have you tried to make `x` global variable, that is declare `x` in the global scope and then initialize it inside the callback?

Comment: Yes, I did try defining the `x` as a global var, but somehow didn't work.

Comment: I have added jsfiddle replicating the issue. Just click on the two names and you will see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `x` here:

```
var x;

$(document).on('click','#timer',function() {
    var timestamp = localStorage.getItem("LivechatExpirationTime");
    var countdown = new Date(timestamp).getTime();
    //alert (countdown)
    var x = setInterval(function () // <-- you redeclare x, so it's different from the first one
```

if you just remove the second `var`, it will work as expected:

```
var x;

$(document).on('click','#timer',function() {
    var timestamp = localStorage.getItem("LivechatExpirationTime");
    var countdown = new Date(timestamp).getTime();
    //alert (countdown)
    x = setInterval(function ()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wosehfc3/

Comment: Wow, what a catch. I was smashing my head on this for so long. Thanks a lot. The bounty is well deserved and yours... just have to wait 22 hours to grant it!